# Setting A $_GET Value From A Previously Defined Variable - PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, search, get

I have a search form in the header of every page on a site that submits info to another page when undertaking a search query via the form's `action` attribute, namely a page called `search.php` and it takes the value of the search `<input>` field and stores it as a variable called `searchQuery`. Using PHP this searches a MySQL database. All of this works as expected.

I would like the value of the search input field to be placed in the URL of the page the search is processed on, again namely `search.php`.

I understand from other questions on SO that you can't add variables to a form's `action` attribute. If I add the key of the query string in the action attribute, the form still works OK:

```
action="search.php?keyword="
```

From this I thought I would be able to then set the `$_GET` value on the `search.php` page by using:

```
if(isset($_POST['search-submit'])) {

    // make this variable available before HTML output
    $searchQuery = htmlspecialchars($_POST['search']);

    $_GET['keyword'] = $searchQuery;
}
```

This however does not work, although it doesn't throw any errors in my PHP error logs.

Because I'm running the script on specific page allocated by the action attribute, I don't think I need to use a `$_SESSION` variable?

**HTML Form**

Here is the form that is on every page in the header

```
<form action="search.php?keyword=" method="POST">
    <label for="search">Enter Search</label>
    <input type="search" name="search" id="search">
    <button type="submit" name="search-submit" id="search-submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: still need to add it to the form `action="search.php?keyword=<?=htmlentities($_GET['keyword'])?>"`

Comment: `action=search?"<?=http_build_query($_GET)?>"`?

Comment: HI @LawrenceCherone - when i use that snippet I get an error `Undefined index: keyword in` that references the line with the form action attribute.

Comment: hi@mickmackusa that directs to `search.php` page but doesn't add the search query as a `$_GET` value (even if I had in the `keyword=` after the `search.php?`

Comment: Why don't you change the form method as `GET` and the search input to `name="keyword"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form set the method to `GET`, remove the query string from the `action` attribute so it is just `search.php`, change the name on the search input field to `keyword` and remove the `name` on the `submit` button.

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <label for="search">Enter Search</label>
    <input type="search" name="keyword" id="search">
    <button type="submit" id="search-submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Then in your `search.php` page, change your initial code to the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    // make this variable available before HTML output
    $searchQuery = htmlspecialchars($_GET['keyword']);
} else {
    header("Location: index.php"); // use whatever page is your home page or preferred page to redirect to
}
```

And then in your search query make sure the `$_GET` value is set:

```
if(isset($_GET['keyword'])) {

    // run your search query using the $searchQuery variable

}
```